# Diode used in H-Bridge Tesla coil power

Tags: h-bridge, tesla-coil

I'm contemplating a new project that is to build a Tesla coil.
After poking Mr. Google for some design, I found 2 popular schematics, one by Richie Burnett and the other by Chester Lowrey. The 2 designs are similar but one thing catch my eye. In both approach, they use a diode to build a half rectified DC input to the bridge but the sizing of the diode and their number differ. In the Burnett's design, he use two 1N5408 in series (rated at 3A/1000V)...

[image]

and in the Lowrey's design, he use a single 30A/400V.

[image]

In the first design, using 2 diodes in series doesn't add much to the circuit since the intrinsic characteristic of the diode is not change (except for the double voltage drop!). And in the second design, 30A seems to me a bit overrated.

So my question is : What would be the right spec for this diode and what are the calculation I could do to derive it?

Thanks!

Comment: 5408 seems a bit on the light side, but Richie Burnett is a well respected figure in this area, and not prone to making mistakes. Note that the 5408 is rated 3A continuous, and 200A half-cycle surge. I suspect he has two in series for redundancy (they tend to fail short) than for reverse withstanding. Have you figured out what the low voltage diode in series with the FETs is for? Me neither. Unless it's to offset any forward voltage of the diodes across the FETs. There are specialist TC forums which will get you a more experienced class of responder.

Comment: @Neil_UK Well, there it is an other big difference between the 2 design. Burnett is using a "small" 1N5822 where Lowrey is using a beefy MBR545!? And both design seems to work but I was interested to understand the math behind this sizing because I can figure it out.

Comment: @Neil_UK BTW, Here the explanation of Richie concerning the added diodes (Series + Parallel) « Isolation of the MOSFET body diodes, using series a Schottky diode and parallel fast recovery diodes eliminates problems due to the slow reverse recovery characteristics of the body diode. »

Comment: Ah! I wondered about the low PIV of those series diodes, but yes, slow body diode sounds right. It depends how much current Richie's is expected to take, once a diode is big enough, it's big enough. 3A continuous is 6A halfwave (assuming still constant drop rather than I2t region) and more than that peak. 340v * (say) 8A peak is 2.7kW, on a 5408. Does that sound enough power? I think I'd use a fatter diode, with my expensive FETs downstream n'all, but if you are controlling for measured current, then it's easy to manage the peak to less than some limit. It does build up slowly you know.